# How do you save wcfg waveform data in Xilinx ISim clock cycle resolution

Tags: simulation, xilinx-ise

I have a simulation that takes 4 hours to run and don't want to repeat it when I have to measure timing. Is there a way to save the data so that I can review it on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulation data is store in a waveform database (*.wdb) file. The waveform configuration file (*.wcfg) contains only the selected signals and its display settings like radix, color, position, grouping, ...

So don't delete the *.wdb file and load/open it on your next run. Don't overwrite it :).